# checking elements in an array in s (through pointers) in C

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, pointers, max

I am studying the pointers and this question became interesting. I want it to be like this: we have two arrays of integers. Determine the value and number of the largest element of the first array that is not part of the second but I don't know how to make the second part of the code that will check if the largest number is not included in the second array

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long array[100], * maximum, size, c, location = 1;

    printf("Enter the number of elements in array\n");
    scanf_s("%ld", &size);

    printf("Enter %ld integers\n", size);

    for (c = 0; c < size; c++)
        scanf_s("%ld", &array[c]);

    maximum = array;
    *maximum = *array;

    for (c = 1; c < size; c++)
    {
        if (*(array + c) > *maximum)
        {
            *maximum = *(array + c);
            location = c + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("Maximum element is present at location number %ld and it's value is %ld.\n", location, *maximum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is the "second array"? `maximum = array;` does not make another array, and `*maximum = *array;` does not copy its content. I suggest using `malloc` and `memcpy`.

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think he has the second array done yet.  But yes, `maximum = array` does nothing here.

Answer (score 1):

For starters your incomplete code already is wrong. It changes the source array

```
maximum = array;

//...

*maximum = *(array + c);
```

More precisely it changes the first element of the array. It shall not do that.

As for your question then the code will look more clear and readable if to implement the algorithm as separate functions.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    const int *p = a;

    while (p != a + n && *p != value) ++p;

    return p != a + n;
}

int * max_exclusive_element( const int a1[], size_t n1, const int a2[], size_t n2 )
{
    const int  *max = a1;

    while (max < a1 + n1 && find( a2, n2, *max ) ) ++max;

    if (max < a1 + n1)
    {
        for ( const int *p = max; ++p < a1 + n1; )
        {
            if ( *max < *p && !find( a2, n2, *p ) )
            {
                max = p;
            }
        }
    }

    return ( int * )( max == a1 + n1 ? NULL : max );
}

int main( void )
{
    int a1[] = { 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    const size_t N1 = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );
    int a2[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );

    int *max = max_exclusive_element( a1, N1, a2, N2 );

    if (max != NULL)
    {
        printf( "Maximum element is present at location number %td and it's value is %d.\n", 
            max - a1, *max );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Maximum element is present at location number 5 and it's value is 8.
```

The function `find` determines whether a given value is present in an array. And the second function `max_exclusive_element` finds the maximum element according to the requirement.

As you can see all loops use pointers.

If you need to use arrays with elements of the type `long int` then it will be not hard to change the presented code.

Comment: "your incomplete code already is wring." --> _wring_ is _wrong_  "your incomplete code already is wrong." 

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing this in the wrong order.  If you find the maximum first and that is in the second array, you need to find the maximum again.  You should first check each number in the first array against the second.  If it is in the second, change the value to `LONG_MIN`.  Then the maximum *will* be the right answer.  Basically something like this:

```
#include <limits.h>

int i = 0;
for (; i < n; ++i) {
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < n; ++j) {
        /* in both arrays? */
        if (arr2[i] == arr1[j]) {
            arr1[j] = LONG_MIN;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

At this point any numbers in `arr1` that are in `arr2` will be set to `LONG_MIN`.  Now just calculate max like you already did.

Edit: changed `INT_MIN` to `LONG_MIN`.  I didn't notice you were doing `long int` arrays.

Comment: C code needs to be in a function, and variables needs to be defined. This is more of an idea than an answer.

Comment: @Jason It vis a bad approach because it changes the source array.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sort of seemed he only needed help with the how.  You know ... logic stuff.  Not syntax stuff.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, for a completely generic approach... sure.  This guy is looking for homework help, and this logic will provide the correct answer.